# Choosing a position in an array with uniform random probability conditioned on it having a specific element

Tags: list-manipulation

I have an array `exArray` with two types of integer elements: `1` and `2`.  I'd like to choose a position $k$ in the array with uniform random probability conditioned on it having an element with the value `1`.  Is there a one-liner to do this?  Right now I'm using `RandomInteger[{1,arrayLength}]`, which is a ridiculous way to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RandomChoice[Flatten[Position[{1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1}, 1]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sjoerd already gave one good option, but depending on the circumstance a proceedural trial-and-error approach may be superior.  If you want to generate a *many* random positions from a given list it would be better to find all "ones" positions and then use `RandomSample` and/or `RandomChoice` to extract what you want.  However if you only want a limited number of random positions from a particular list it will be much faster to merely generate a random position, extract that element and check it, and start over if it is not the target type.  Here is an example:

```
n = 5000000;
a = RandomInteger[{1, 2}, n];
RandomChoice[Join @@ Position[a, 1]] // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.983, 4227176}
> ```

So it takes almost a second (on my machine) to pick a random "one" from the five million element list `a`.  However we can generate 50,000 random "ones" positions in a fraction of the time with trial-and-error:

```
Table[
  For[p = 0, a[[p]] =!= 1, p = RandomInteger[{1, n}]]; p,
  {50000}
] // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.156
> ```

So a single random position takes about 3.12*10^-6 seconds.  This assumes a uniform distribution of ones and non-ones, and a smaller percent of "target" values will result in longer average times, but I hope this illustrates the potential performance of this method.